# Django: Keep order when translating list to custom dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

when I get a list of objects via

```
tests = Test.objects.all().order_by('-order')
```

I get all objects in the right order 3,2,1 (order is a integer field).

But after I run

```
response = {}
for test in tests:
    response.update({
        test.slug: {
            'obj': test
        }
    })
```

The objects are in order 3,1,2.

How can I create my custom dictionary but keep the order?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to maintain order.

Comment: Please people learn to use dicts... `response.update({test.slug: whatever})` is an inefficient and overcomplexificated way to write `reponse[test.slug] = whatever`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

anyname = OrderedDict()
```

Fill your dictionary and you will get the same order in output.